# Solve this inequality $e^{-x} + 2e^{-x/2} > 1$.

Tags: inequality, exponential-function

Solve this inequality $e^{-x} + 2e^{-x/2} > 1$. According to WolframAlpha, it's $x < 2\log(1 + \sqrt{2})$. How does one get this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

$$y=e^{-x/2}\\
y^2+2y>1$$

Comment: Can the downvoter explain the mistakes in the post?